# photo not in any album facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

i've noticed that there are some photos that doesn't appear in any albums. This photos are published by fan on a facebook page. 
Is there any way to get this photos by the API ?
The API call /feed returns all the posts of the wall, but many of this photo that i seen in the wall on browser doesn't appear in the response of the API.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<YOUR_PAGE_NAME>/picture
```

Hope this help

Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/photos
```

Permissions Needed: `user_photo_video_tags` or `friends_photo_video_tags`.

refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ user photos

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos

I have a live example of this usage is you wish to test.  it is an iframe plugin that feeds the photos for a page.  "is not set up for users". 
Just replace "anotherfeed" page user name with any page.

https://anotherfeed.com/api.beta.php?type=photos&pageid=anotherfeed&width=350&height=500&limit=20&offset=0